# Proof of B1by OLS in a multiple regression model with dummies

Tags: mathematical-statistics, least-squares, binary-data

Given the model Y=B0 + B1C + B2A + e, where C=(0,1) and A=(0,1), how can I derive the formula for the estimator of B1 by OLS? I already know the formula for the general case in which A and C are not dummies and starting from that I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Because there is no difference in the formulas, nor in how they can be derived, could you please clarify how you think this is a distinct situation?

Comment: Also, not every "set" of binary variates are _dummy_ varites. So are you speaking of dummy, i.e. mutually exclusive categories?

Comment: I am so sorry for the misunderstanding, but I mean, which is the final result when I try to substitute C and A with 0 and 1? For example when c=0 and = a=1, c=1 and a=1, c=0 and a=0, c=1 and a=0. When i only have one dummy variable in a single regression model the estiamator for B1 is equal to the difference between the sample average of y when c=1 and the sample average of y when c=0

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much to it actually.
You have

$$Y=\beta X+\epsilon$$

Where the columns of $X$ are given by:

$$X_i=\left[\begin{matrix}1 \\ A_i \\ B_i\end{matrix}\right], A_i \in \{0,1\},B_i \in \{0,1\}$$

$\beta$ can be obtained just like in OLS:

$$\beta = YX^T(XX^T)^{-1}$$

We have that:

$$XX^T=
\left[\begin{matrix}
\mathbf 1\\A\\B\end{matrix}\right]
\left[\begin{matrix}
\mathbf 1^T&A^T&B^T\end{matrix}\right]=
\left[\begin{matrix}
\mathbf {11}^T & \mathbf {1}A^T & \mathbf {1}B^T\\
A\mathbf {1}^T & AA^T & AB^T\\
B\mathbf {1}^T & BA^T & BB^T
\end{matrix}\right]=
n \left[\begin{matrix}
1 & \mu_A & \mu_B\\
\mu_A & \mu_A & \mu_{A\cap B}\\
\mu_B & \mu_{A\cap B} & \mu_B
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

This matrix is invertible if $\mu_A \neq 0, \mu_B \neq 0$ and $\mu_{A \cap B}$ cannot be equal to $\mu_A, \mu_B$ at the same time (that would mean $A$ and $B$ are the same).

$$\begin{cases}
\mu_A = (1/n)\sum_i^n A_i\\
\mu_B = (1/n)\sum_i^n B_i\\
\mu_{A\cap B} = (1/n)\sum_i^n A_iB_i
\end{cases}$$

Assuming you calculated the solution for $\beta$, then you are left with a model:

$$\hat Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_A A_i + \beta_B B_i$$

We are left with four possible combinations of $A_i, B_i$

$$\hat Y_i = \begin{cases}
\beta_0 & \{A_i := 0, B_i := 0\}  \\
\beta_0+\beta_A & \{A_i := 1, B_i := 0\}  \\
\beta_0+\beta_B & \{A_i := 0, B_i := 1\}\\
\beta_0+\beta_A+\beta_B & \{A_i := 1, B_i := 1\}\\
\end{cases}$$

So, interpretation is straightforward: each entry here represents conditional expected values.
$\beta_A$ therefore represents an increase (even if negative) of the expected value if $A_i = 1$ compared with the samples where both $A_i = B_i = 0$.
Similarly for $\beta_B$.